# Paint.Net darken selected pixels?

Tags: paint.net

how do i darken the selected pixels? (eg move them closer to black).

I have some thin grey lines in a picture but they are not visible when i print out the image. I can select them using the magic wand but i dont know how to make them darker..

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this.  One option is to adjust the Brightness/Contrast or Hue/Saturation (look under "Adjustments".)  Another is to zoom in so you are close enough to click accurately on the one-pixel-wide line and use the paint bucket tool with a darker color.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried several methods to make a scanned signature look better in Paint.NET, and while I've been able to change the signature's color using the Brightness/Contrast method mentioned previously, I still wasn't satisfied with the image.  After some experimentation, I found that "thickening" the signature lines is very effective and can be done with the following steps:

- Use the "magic wand" (or your preferred selection method) to select the outline
- Click "Layers"->"Duplicate Layer"
- Your newly created layer will be selected, so click "Layers"->"Rotate / Zoom"
- Increase the zoom level from 1.0 upwards until the outline is at the desired thickness.  Somewhere between 1.02 and 1.05 usually works for me.
- After clicking "OK", click "Layers"->"Merge Layer Down"
- For added thickness/sharpness, use the "Effects"->"Selection"->"Outline Selection" tool.  Note that this took is part of a [plug-in pack](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/forum/44-plugin-packs).